# How to use 2 model in same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use 2 models, `model_1` and `model_2` (one `model_1`, many `model_2`) but in one view I can use only one.

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectFashion.Models.model_1>
@model IEnumerable<ProjectFashion.Models.model_2>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VMenu";
}
<ul>
    @foreach(var n in Model) {
        <li class="dir">
            <h6>@n.name</h6>
                <ul>
                      @*I WANT TO GET model_2 which belongs to model_1*@
                </ul>
        </li>        
    }
</ul>
```

and my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!--vmenu-->
@Html.Action("VMenu", "Layout")
<!--vmenu-->
```

and my LayoutController.cs:

```
ShopContent db = new ShopContent();
public ActionResult VMenu() {
    return PartialView("_VMenu", db.model_1s);
}
```

I also use `model_3` to include `model_1` and `model_2` but some problems occur in `@Html.Action("VMenu", "Layout")`.
(I am sorry about my imperfect English...)

Comment: This looks a *lot* like ASP.NET MVC code, but the random assortment of tags says otherwise.  Can you clarify?  What on Earth does this have to do with Python or multiple mobile platforms?

Comment: -1 for a lot of tags but none of them relevant (this looks like ASP.NET MVC/Razor?) for starters, and a very unclear question after this is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want this:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectFashion.Models.model_1>
@model IEnumerable<ProjectFashion.Models.model_2>
```

You want this:

```
@model ProjectFashion.Models.SomeCustomModel
```

Your custom model could be as simple as this:

```
public class SomeCustomModel
{
    public IEnumerable<model_1> FirstModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<model_2> SecondModel { get; set; }
}
```

(I couldn't come up with better names, your model names didn't really leave any clues about what they are.)

Then in your controller action you'd create an instance of `SomeCustomModel`, populate its fields, and return that to the view.  In general terms, what you're creating is a "composite object" which simply consists of other objects.

This is assuming, of course, that your models don't have any other existing relationship to each other.  (Again, the names don't give any clues.)  If they do, perhaps there's a "parent" object which has "child" objects already?  Maybe `model_1` contains a property of type `model_2` or a collection of `model_2` instances already?

Comment: i tried it, but another problem is that @foreach(var item in Model.FirstModel) and
the error is that Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @user2494355: What isn't instantiated?  How are you building the model before passing it to the view?  Chances are you're trying to enumerate on a null list.  If it's possible that the list of objects is never set then you'd want to instantiate it to an empty list by default.  In the view model's constructor simply set the property to an empty list.

Comment: you're right........ my english still limited so i couldn't understand well, but finally i did it, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a navigation property on model_1 that gives you the related model_2's?  If so, then you only need to pass the model_1 with the navigation model_2 filled in.  You would reference it in your sample line as something like `@n.model_2s.property`.